# lat lng to neighborhood info

Tags: geolocation, geo, zipcode

Is there a dynamic hierarchical data source out there that I can use to identify a lat lng point into a neighborhood?

For instance, if I was in Manhattan, it would recognize that I'm in Chinatown, Manhattan, New York City in that order.  And if I was in a less densely populated area it would just put me into a neighborhood that would span a larger area.  It can be a bit fuzzy in this concept.

Ultimately I want to group people into their nearest neighobrhood given evenly sized neighborhood population.

I know that zip codes can roll up into a metro area, but I wonder if there is something that's more granular or more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

[Google's geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) can give a variety of levels of detail about a location. It varies by region, country, and even at state/local levels but you should be able to get close to what you're looking for.